# Cloth simulation ripping mesh

Tags: physics

In 2.79Blender-Internal,I have been trying to simulate the path of a rigid body on a cloth like surface.However,the cloth(cube) gets ripped when the rigid body(sphere) comes in contact with it.
Following settings have been used to stop this behaviour [but it still rips!]

**

> cloth structural stiffness - 1500
>     particle permeability - 0
>     collision
>   absorption - 1
>   rigid body collider mass - 0.001

[image: ClothRip]

**

For further clarity ,please refer the attached the blend file .
[image]

How to stop this ripping?

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/96789/29586