# Why is the mesh not colliding with cloth simulation?

Tags: physics, collision

Why is the Suzanne falling through the carpet? Suzanne has collision and rigid body physics and the floor has cloth physics with collision. I want Suzanne to fall on the cloth and it should slide on the cloth. what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's some difficulties for rigid body cloth collisions. Make sure to set the rigid body to mesh for the cloth and set it to be final so it can take into account the cloth modifier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make rigid body interact with softbody physics?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96744/is-there-a-way-to-make-rigid-body-interact-with-softbody-physics)

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer already given here:

[Is there a way to make rigid body interact with softbody physics?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96744/is-there-a-way-to-make-rigid-body-interact-with-softbody-physics)

Unfortunately, I found out that there is a bug report because this doesn't seem to work anymore. I tried myself and can only get this result in Blender 2.79 while in 2.83 and 2.91 the rigid body doesn't take the deforming of the soft body into account.

So, one solution might be (as long as it's not fixed in newer versions) to simulate this in 2.79, bake the simulation and convert it to keyframes, then open it in a current version of Blender.